# Import Indian stock prices into R

Tags: r, finance, web

Is there a way to import stock price data from Indian stock markets - BSE and NSE into R?
I would like to know if there is a package that does what quantmod does from american markets.
Any other way this could be approached?

Answer (score 7):

quantmod does it.  Just use the yahoo symbol.  (or use the google symbol and use `src="google"` in the `getSymbols` call)

e.g.

```
getSymbols("HDFCBANK.BO", src="yahoo")
getSymbols("IDFC.NS", src="yahoo")
```

Comment: But how to know the exact name to provide for various tasks? any global dictionary is avlbl?

Comment: you can use stockSymbols() function to get whole list of companies.

Comment: `getSymbols("HDFCBANK.BO", src="google")
Error: ‘getSymbols.google’ is defunct.
Google Finance stopped providing data in March, 2018.
You could try setting src = "yahoo" instead.
See help("Defunct") and help("quantmod-defunct")`

Answer (score 3):

Use common notation which is present on yahoo/google and then use

> .BO for BSE

and

> .NS for NSE

```
getSymbols("SBIN.BO", src="yahoo")
getSymbols("SBIN.NS", src="yahoo")
```