# How to get Indian Stock market Index data in r?

Tags: r, quantmod

I was trying to get **BSE SENSEX** data in R and came across this [Import Indian stock prices into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302434/import-indian-stock-prices-into-r) which is useful but I am not able to get SENSEX Index data using `getSymbols` from `quantmod`.

I have tried many options but none of them worked

`quantmod::getSymbols("SENSEX", src="yahoo")`

`quantmod::getSymbols("SENSEX.BO", src="yahoo")`

`quantmod::getSymbols("BSE SENSEX", src="yahoo")`

`quantmod::getSymbols("BSE SENSEX.BO", src="yahoo")`

About Sensex:

[image: SENSEX]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages `tidyquant` and`Quantmod` uses Yahoo Finance. Therefore, check what the security is called on their website, hence: [^BSESN](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EBSESN/)

```
library(tidyquant)

tq_get("^BSESN") 

# A tibble: 2,643 × 8
   symbol date         open   high    low  close volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 ^BSESN 2012-01-03 15641. 15970. 15641. 15939.  16200   15939.
 2 ^BSESN 2012-01-04 15967. 16005. 15822. 15883.  17800   15883.
 3 ^BSESN 2012-01-05 15893. 15980. 15809. 15857.  21200   15857.
 4 ^BSESN 2012-01-06 15789. 16001. 15665. 15868.  17200   15868.
 5 ^BSESN 2012-01-07    NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA 
 6 ^BSESN 2012-01-09 15840. 15872. 15678. 15815.  11200   15815.
 7 ^BSESN 2012-01-10 15898. 16181. 15898. 16165.  19600   16165.
 8 ^BSESN 2012-01-11 16222. 16245. 16128. 16176.  18600   16176.
 9 ^BSESN 2012-01-12 16117. 16179. 15963. 16038.  14400   16038.
10 ^BSESN 2012-01-13 16145. 16257. 16050. 16155.  19600   16155.
# … with 2,633 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, will accept the answer as soon as SO will let me accept it.